# How to fix Page Not Found (404) error in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

**How to fix this error in django 3.0, when im trying to reach a page using form post method, I getting this error**

Hi, Im new to Django programming language, Now im developing a college project in django, When Im using forms to create login in **POST** method. If I put it on main page, It's working well. But when I put the forms into inside of another page (about.html) I got this error. I can't fix it. So guys Please help me..

```
> Page not found (404) Request Method:  POST Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/login Using the URLconf defined in
> mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> 
> [name='home'] login/ about/ admin/ The current path, about/login,
> didn't match any of these.
> 
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
> settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
> standard 404 page.
```

app/ Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('', views.about, name="about"),
path('', views.login, name="login")
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

project/ urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


from pages.views import home, about, login
urlpatterns = [
path('',home,name='home'),
path('login/',login),
path('about/',about),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "test.html")

def about(request,*args, **kwargs):
    return render(request,"inner.html")

def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "result.html")
```

HTML FORM

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <label> username</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        <label> Password</label>
        <input type="Password" name="upwd"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You main problem in `action="login"`
First write `action="/login"` for resolve you problem, because now you add `login` to current opened url

Comment: facing Run_Time error                                                                                                
 "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/login/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings."

Comment: If I set APPEND_SLASH = False, then i get same error

Comment: Try /login/ for action